# How to retrieve data from geoalchemy2 Query result?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, gis, geoalchemy2

Code snippet

```
from dbinit import session
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry, func
result = session.query(func.ST_AsText('POINT(100 100)'))
```

How to retrieve the data from this `result` object?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution.

`re = result.all()`